# Qt new QWidget opens new window

Tags: qt, qwidget

I'm creating a new subuclass of `QWidget` with: `new TestView;`
When I call that statement, a new window opens.

Further when I add this widget to a layout, the window "closes" and the widget is shown in the layout as it should in the first place.

How do I make sure that the widget isn't displayed as a new window?

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I make sure that the widget isn't displayed as a new window?

It happens because your widget is visible before you add it to the layout. Either you are calling `show()` or `raise()` early on your `TestView` object, or you do the same on a parent widget between its creation and the moment it is added to the layout.

If you are making visible your widgets in their constructors, that's a really bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i found that i could do this little hack where i disable the visibility of the widget just before adding it to the layout and re-enable just after:

```
self.widget.setVisible(False)
self.tab.layout().addWidget(self.widget)
self.widget.setVisible(True)
```

Hope it works for at least someone out there!

(this is for PySide2 btw)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I did not specify the parent. That happened to me twice today.

First, I defined the constructor as following:

```
Class:Class(QWidget *parent){...
```

instead of

```
Class:Class(QWidget *parent) : QComboBox(parent){...
```

Then, just a few hours later, I created a QT object without setting the parent:

```
... = new QPushButton();
```

Both of these mistakes caused the problem you encountered.